# C# Write in an excel with Interop file already populated

Tags: c#, excel

I have some data saved in some strings, now I would like to open an existing Excel file, and write these strings in order in the empty cells after the populated ones,

Example:
I have the file that in column A is written up to 10, I would like the code to check that 10 finds a datum and writes to 11 and then continue [11, B] [11, C] until I finish the strings and then save the file.

I'm using Interop

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    OpenFileDialog FileExcel = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (FileExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            var sr = new StreamReader(FileExcel.FileName);
        }
        catch (SecurityException ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show($"Security error.\n\nError message: {ex.Message}\n\n" +
            $"Details:\n\n{ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }

    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileExcel.FileName);
    Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedItem)];
    Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

    int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
    int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
        {
            //new line
            if (j == 1)
                Console.Write("\r\n");
            //write the value to the console
            if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
               Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");

            //add useful things here!   
        }
    }
```

Comment: why are you using Interop? It's complicated, unreliable and pointlessly opens Excel. It's a legacy tech, really. Use one of the many free libraries available for .NET which can write to the file directly without having to open the Excel application first. Your code will be more reliable, and you may find it's easier to solve this issue, too.

Comment: @ADyson what library should i use? If you can give me an example, I would be grateful :-)

Comment: It's trivial to search for them online, did you try? EPPlus, NPOI, ClosedXML and many more. https://nugetmusthaves.com/article/top-excel-libraries has a good list.